# Cross validation R2 values larger than 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm training a random forest model with around 70 features. After a 10 fold cross-validation my mean R-square value is 37...which does not make sense. I paste my code below, can anyone help?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50, random_state=1)

rf.fit(X, y)
print('training R2 = ' + str(round(rf.score(X, y), 3)))
print('training RMSE = %.3f' % np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true=y, y_pred=rf.predict(X))))
```

---

```
# compute cross validation scores for random forest model
r2_scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, scoring='r2', cv=crossvalidation, n_jobs=-1)
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=crossvalidation, n_jobs=-1)
rmse_scores = [np.sqrt(abs(s)) for s in scores]

print('Cross-validation results:')
print('Folds: %i, mean R2: %.3f' % (len(scores), np.mean(r2_scores)))
print('Folds: %i, mean RMSE: %.3f' % (len(scores), np.mean(np.abs(rmse_scores))))
```

Comment: What is the value of `crossvalidation` variable ? can you please paste the whole code ? Also, instead of mean print out the whole output that you are getting as well.

Comment: the crossvalidation is [code](crossvalidation = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=1)), and here's the whole output of r2_scores: [-4.40366709e-01  7.62311578e-01 -2.23797817e-01 -8.04020084e+00
  2.97780893e-01 -8.67987394e+00 -3.11319193e+02 -1.10036708e+01
 -2.65264135e+01  4.42674199e-01]